# Copy Paste Special Value - Vlookup Edition

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am an accountant dealing with lots of financial statements.

I typically use a vlookup to pull in numbers from another spreadsheet into my template containing the desired format. The best solution has been for me to

1. Copy my Vlookup formula
2. Select the whole template
3. F5-> Special-> Search for Blanks
4. Copy paste special formulas

Here's my problem. My desired template contains sum formulas etc that I do not want to lose. However, after I copy paste special formula and try to copy paste special value, I cannot as Excel says it cannot work on multiple selections. Then it becomes a painful task going through line by line and converting the vlookup into a value. Any solutions?

Comment: Welcome to Super User,, please [edit] your post and share some sample data & used formula to that we can understand the situation and fix it !

Answer (score 0):

Well, VBA is the gold standard for this kind of problem:  "gruntwork" that needs to not be "gruntwork." However, there is somewhat of a workaround available to you.

First, to clarify your question, I believe your approach is meant to paste the formula (singular) into multiple cells, and then it acts upon information relative to those cells producing different results (probably) in all the cells it is present in. You then want to copy those (different) results and paste them (in one step) as values. And it is at the point where you attempt to copy these for that last step that Excel balks. Choosing a big block is unacceptable as it would include your desired subtotal formulas and so turn them to values as well upon pasting.

No way around that. People have been asking for some time now for Excel to overcome that, but Excel has a feature wherein non-contiguous cells can be copied and pasted as a contiguous set of data... BUT... if it cannot figure out how to render what you want copied, it stops you right at the start and refuses to go onward.

So, here's the deal...

Conceptually, this is in keeping with the idea of a template, so it shouldn't be too obnxious. Highlight all the cells and paste special the formulas. Let Excel calculate and then start the macro recorder (click the little camera looking icon in the absolute lower left corner of the screen by the word "Ready") and give it a name and a shortcut key combo (if desired). When that dialogue box goes away, start the work. For every cell, one by one, you will press `F2`, notice that the cursor is at the absolute end of the entire formula in the cell, press `Ctrl-Shift-Home` to highlight everything in the cell, then immediately press `F9` and notice the whole formula is evaluated and replaced with its result. Then press `Enter` which moves you to the next highlighted cell (handy that). Repeat for every cell until the highlight returns to the first cell you did it for (actually, it doesn't matter if you go on too far and do a couple twice, just don't stop short). Do be careful pressing keys so you don't break the highlighting. The click the rather different looking icon down where the camera looking thing was to end the recording.

It IS a solution using VBA but takes no knowledge of actual VBA to do it. That's my wiggle-room... At this point you have a template with a macro and must save it as an XLSM type file:  in this case, as an XLTM file. Well, if you had it as an actual formal template. If you're like me, you have a bunch of "templates" that just have normal XLSX file types and in that case, XLSM would be fine.

Further issues:  if you distribute the filled in templates, just do all this, then save the results as an XLSX file, the doing of which will dump the macro so the client will not have either a macro workbook which many would not like, nor will see you worked smarter, not harder and try to lower your rates! Presumably YOU have no problems with a macro file, but if you do, you can save the macro to your Personal workbook so it is available always but is not in your template.

Also, if you bring up the macro editor, you can see how it did its magic and see how easily you could insert lines for new cells getting the `VLOOKUP()` formula, or remove lines for cells no longer getting it.

Finally, to really future-proof the macro, select the cell with your `VLOOKUP()` formul, then start the macro recorder, as above, but your first step will be to copy that cell (just use `Ctrl-C` perhaps) and your second to perform the `F5` highlighting the blank cells for the formula, then `Paste|Special|Formula` to the highlighted cells. THEN you begin the cycle of `F2`, `Ctrl-Shift-Home`, `F9`, and `Enter` to go through the cells. That way the whole thing is done for you. Personally... I'm a throwback who'd prefer to do that easy first part by hand, then have the macro do the rest, but no one should live that way, right?

So... the workaround does still use a macro, but you won't have to do the VBA yourself so I'm calling it even there. You can have the macro in the template, or not, as needed, and in any case, not pass anything involving it on to clients so I'm calling it win there. Finally, whichever approach above is taken (just getting values in the end or having it do the whole step of work), you aren't doing it piece by piece, so a win there too.

(But if you don't mind VBA, it could all be done in 3-4 lines I'd say, since written VBA can use vastly more effective commands than the macro recorder is able to risk.)